Writing kernel layer on UART driver
I want to take leverage the existing kernel API/module to create packet layer abstraction for user space application to transfer "packets" via UART interface.
So, the intention is a kernel module that does the following

Uses different module to read UART bytes (I'm not sure what I should use, I can see "usbserial" available, but not sure if it can be extended that way). Or maybe I should use a filesystem?

After reading a certain number of bytes do some calculation on in, like crc, type etc. And then transfers the packet to the user space program

User space program can use poll mechanism to get notified, and then read the entire packet.


How can I build such a thing? I'm having trouble connecting the pieces, and google/chatgpt is not helping. Any example that does something similar would be awesome, thanks!
edit:
As a packet I'm referring to an internal data structure, nothing to do with any other protocol.

At the kernel level, various modules register a "TTY line discipline" such as PPP, and userspace can attach a specific line discipline to the TTY device after opening it. One problem with this approach is that line disciplines are identified by a small integer in the range 0 to NR_LDISCS-1 (defined by #include <linux/tty.h>) and the number increases as new line disciplines are added to the kernel sources. For development, you would need to steal one of the existing line discipline numbers. A few of them are only of historical or niche importance. (Kernel 5.18 onwards has N_DEVELOPMENT.)

Another option is to write a "serdev" device driver, but such devices need to be defined in a device tree or ACPI.

As @IanAbbott said, use serdev approach for the modern kernels (v6.1+ will suffice). For the older one I wouldn't even spent a minute to develop anything.
